# How to search in a general tree a node in Java nonrecursive

Tags: java, recursion, search, tree

I am new to Java so any advice would be really appreciated.
I have a tree-like File System with files and directories. I want to find a Directory by its name.
Component is an interface and both File and Directory implement it.
I wrote this method in the class Directory in order to find a Directory named name.

```java
public Directory getDir(String name) {
    Iterator<Component> iterator = (Iterator<Component>)components.iterator();
    Component component = null; 
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        component = iterator.next();
        if(component instanceof Directory) {
            if(component.getName().equals(name))
                return (Directory) component;
            else component.getDir(name);
         }
     }  
    return null;
}
```

Somehow, this method won't stop after finding my Directory.
I tried writing "`return component.getDir(name)`" but it doesn't help. It won't search in every component of my node, just in the first one.
What am I doing wrong?
Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your line:
 `else component.getDir(name)` is not checked for a return value. No matter whether that recursive call returns a found directory or null (nothing found), the next thing will be another round in the loop.

Just check whether it returns not null, then return this again.